# Getting an error -Error HH308: Unrecognized positional argument scripts/deploy.js

Tags: nft, hardhat

Ia m trying to run the command:

```
npx hardhat run src/backend/ scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

But it gives error:

> Error HH308: Unrecognized positional argument scripts/deploy.js

can anyone help?

Comment: You have a space between `src/backend/` and `scripts/deploy.js` so the CLI recognizes it as 2 separate arguments - not 1 argument with the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```